# How to remove first occurrence in string repeatedly python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am not sure how to continously change the first occurance in a list. For instance, I will have a list of numbers

```
import numpy as np
test=np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,1,1])
```

Which gives me an output of

```
array([ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan,   1.,   1.])
```

I want to use a function to change this to

```
array([ nan,  nan,   nan,   1.,   1.,  nan,   nan,   1.])
```

which removes the first instance of 1 each time it starts.

Comment: what have you attempted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
idx = np.diff(np.append(False,(test==1)).astype(int))==1
test[idx] = np.nan
```

**Sample runs**

1) Sample case from posted question -

```
In [80]: test
Out[80]: array([ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan,   1.,   1.])

In [81]: test[np.diff(np.append(False,(test==1)).astype(int))==1] = np.nan

In [82]: test
Out[82]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,  nan,  nan,   1.])
```

2) Special case with a `1` at the start -

```
In [72]: test
Out[72]: array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])

In [73]: test[np.diff(np.append(False,(test==1)).astype(int))==1] = np.nan

In [74]: test
Out[74]: array([ nan,   1.,   0.,  nan,   0.,   0.,  nan,   1.,   0.,  nan])
```

Comment: Had you tried a little harder, you could have obfuscated / uglified this even further by using the whole first part directly as an indexing operation. I call lazy! :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Fulfilled that wish in sample run ;)

Comment: ahahahah, I spoke too soon! :p

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that `nan` times anything is `nan`.

```
import numpy as np
test=np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,1,1])

test[1:] *= test[:-1]
test[0] = np.nan

print test
# [ nan  nan  nan   1.   1.  nan  nan   1.]
```